# How to create iam-user module in terraform to cover 3 type of iam-user scenarios

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-modules

Can you please help here on how to create iam-user module in terraform to cover 3 type of iam-user scenarios ?

PS: I don't want to create nested directory under modules/iam/iam-user/ to make each iam-user cases separately.

Following are the scenarios:

```
// Type 1
resource "aws_iam_user" "aws_iam_user_000" {
  name                 = "user-000"
  permissions_boundary = data.aws_iam_policy.permission_boundary.arn
}

resource "aws_iam_user_policy_attachment" "aws_iam_user_000" {
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.s3_iam_policy.arn
  user       = aws_iam_user.aws_iam_user_000.name
}

// Type 2

resource "aws_iam_user" "aws_iam_user_001" {
  path                 = "/"
  for_each             = toset(var.user_lists)
  name                 = each.value
  force_destroy        = true
  permissions_boundary = data.aws_iam_policy.permission_boundary.arn
}

resource "aws_iam_group" "aws_iam_group_001" {
  name = "group-0001"
}
resource "aws_iam_user_group_membership" "group-membership" {
  for_each = toset(var.user_lists)
  user     = aws_iam_user.aws_iam_user_001[each.value].name
  groups   = [aws_iam_group.aws_iam_group_001.name]
}

// Type 3

resource "aws_iam_user" "aws_iam_user_0002" {
  name                 = "user-002"
  tags                 = { "user_type" = "admin_account" }
  permissions_boundary = data.aws_iam_policy.permission_boundary.arn
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you should be able to accomplish this using `count` and `for_each` with variables as below.

#### variables.tf

```
variable "is_admin" {
  type    = bool
  default = false
}

variable "user_lists" {
  type    = list(any)
  default = null
}
```

#### main.tf

```
// Type 1 and Type 3
resource "aws_iam_user" "this" {
  count = var.user_lists == null ? 1 : 0

  name                 = var.is_admin ? "user-000" : "user-002"
  permissions_boundary = data.aws_iam_policy.permission_boundary.arn
  tags                 = var.is_admin ? { "user_type" = "admin_account" } : null
}

resource "aws_iam_user_policy_attachment" "this" {
  count = var.user_lists == null ? 1 : 0

  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.s3_iam_policy.arn
  user       = aws_iam_user.this[0].name
}

// Type 2
resource "aws_iam_user" "from_list" {
  for_each = var.user_lists != null ? toset(var.user_lists) : []

  path                 = "/"
  name                 = each.value
  force_destroy        = true
  permissions_boundary = data.aws_iam_policy.permission_boundary.arn
}

resource "aws_iam_group" "from_list" {
  count = var.user_lists == null ? 1 : 0

  name = "group-0001"
}

resource "aws_iam_user_group_membership" "this" {
  for_each = var.user_lists != null ? toset(var.user_lists) : []

  user   = aws_iam_user.from_list[each.value].name
  groups = [aws_iam_group.from_list[0].name]
}
```